# i have new case in using sign in form with spring and mongodb the error in findOne

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a problem in `findOne` statement; I want to get username to make a login function in my application by an exiting username:

#### Spring Code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/enduser")

public class enduserRestCountroller {
    
    @Autowired
    enduserRepository enduserRepository;
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;
    
     //create
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void create(@RequestBody enduser enduser){
    enduserRepository.save(enduser);
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    
    public List<enduser> readall(  ){
    return enduserRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)

    @CrossOrigin

    public @ResponseBody enduser read(@PathVariable String id){
    return enduserRepository.findOne(id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void update(@RequestBody enduser enduser){
        enduserRepository.save(enduser);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteuser/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String delete(@PathVariable String id){
        enduserRepository.delete(id);
        return "1";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin/{username}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public enduser login(@PathVariable String username){
         
        System.out.println(username);
         
        username="maged";
        
        Query query=new Query();
        
        enduser user=mongoOperations.
                findOne(
                        query.addCriteria(
                                Criteria.where("username")
                                        .is(username)),enduser.class);
        
        System.out.println("enduser is "+user.getUsername());
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Null pointer Exception**

> undefined 2017-10-03 13:24:11.353 ERROR 5668 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
> com.adams.demo.RestController.enduserRestCountroller.login(enduserRestCountroller.java:84)
> ~[classes/:na]

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are missing an @Autowired annotation for MongoOperations:

```
@Autowired
enduserRepository enduserRepository;
@Autowired
MongoOperations mongoOperations;
```

You should also try to separate the [logic](https://github.com/marcnuri-demo/spring-mongo-sequences/blob/SOF-46543859/src/main/java/com/marcnuri/demo/springmongosequences/EnduserService.java) from your [Controller](https://github.com/marcnuri-demo/spring-mongo-sequences/blob/SOF-46543859/src/main/java/com/marcnuri/demo/springmongosequences/EnduserController.java) and to user Java naming conventions for you classes.

You can find a working example here:

[Mongo Enduser example](https://github.com/marcnuri-demo/spring-mongo-sequences/tree/SOF-46543859)

Download the branch and do a `gradle bootRun` in your command line.
You can then navigate in your browser to
http://localhost:8080/enduser/adduser/test in order to create a demo user

and to
http://localhost:8080/enduser/signin/test in order to test your method.

The project related classes for this answer are:

- Enduser
- EnduserService
- EnduserController